# Javascript Date object return same hour for different timestamps

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have two separate timestamps:
*'2021-03-28T02:00:00'* and *'2021-03-28T03:00:00'*

Both dates return the same JS timestamp:
Sun Mar 28 2021 03:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

I believe this is because Central European Summer time starts 2021-03-28T02:00:00 but then I would expect 2021-03-28T03:00:00 to return 04:00:00 and not 03:00:00.

In short. I need the date *'2021-03-28T02:00:00'* to return:
Sun Mar 28 2021 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

How come this is not what I am getting? why do I get the same timestamp from the two different dates?

Comment: _"but then I would expect 2021-03-28T03:00:00 to return 04:00:00"_ - no, that makes no sense. _At_ 2:00:00, the clock gets moved one hour forward, to 3:00:00. That does not make any time _after_ that move ahead by an hour as well.

Comment: _"why do I get the same timestamp from the two different dates?"_ - switching from winter to summer time "steals" an hour. Anything in between the two, for example `2021-03-28T02:30:00`, simply does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

**2021-03-28T02:00:00** cannot return what you want because such a time doesn't exist in practice. One second earlier, **2021-03-28T001:59:59 GMT+0100** exists, but as soon as the next second elapses the time becomes  **03:00:00 GMT+0200**.

You will have to modify your surrounding code in some other way, to remove the 'need' to display an impossible time.